# I have a list of 100 elements and I would like to tabulate it into a 10x10 table in excel, using import csv

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of size 100, and I would like to arrange these 100 elements in the list into a 10x10 table in a csv file. I am able to write my data into a csv file, but they are all aligned in 1 row instead of a 10x10 table

```
r = np.random.uniform(0,1,100)
X1 = (np.log(1-r))/-(1/3)

with open('Table.csv','w',newline='') as f:
    thewriter = csv.writer(f)
    thewriter.writerow(X1)
```

Comment: try a `X1 = X1.reshape((10,10))` before writing it, or start out with a 10x10 simply by `r = np.random.uniform(0,1,(10,10))`

Answer (score 1):

Doku: [writer-objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#writer-objects)

> `csvwriter.writerow(row)`
>   Write the row parameter to the writer’s file object, formatted according to the current dialect.

You pass your data as single line to `writerow(data)` - you need to write single rows for all of your data instead:

```
arr = [ i for i in range(100)]   # 100 numbers in one list

import csv

with open ("f.txt", "w", newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for i in range(0,100,10):
        writer.writerow(arr[i:i+10])    # write single row's of 10 numbers each

print(open("f.txt").read())
```

Output:

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19
20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29
30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39
40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49
50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59
60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69
70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79
80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89
90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99
```

---

Alternatively you could partition your data into an iterable of iterables and write all at once using

> `csvwriter.writerows(rows)`
>   Write all elements in rows (an iterable of row objects as described above) to the writer’s file object, formatted according to the current dialect.